# Get database server version failed: mssqlmng failed: Login failed for user

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, hosting, plesk

I am getting following error when I try to create database in Plesk:

> Error: The test connection to the database server has failed because
>   of network problems:
>
> Get database server version failed: mssqlmng failed: Login failed for
>   user 'Abelldatabase'. at (VADOConnection::open line 48) at Unable to
>   ADO conect with connection string: Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Initial
>   Catalog=master;Data
>   Source=132.148.129.64(VADODatabaseProvider::connect line 182) at
>   execute console command --get-server-version(vconsoleapp::start line
>   100) at execute "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\admin\bin\mssqlmng.exe" --get-server-version
>   "--server=132.148.129.64" "--login=Abelldatabase"
>   "--password=*"(vconsoleapp::run line 117) (Error code 1)

[see screenshot of my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pt1fc.png)

Comment: Maybe you forgot to enter correct password for user Abelldatabase or this user doesn't event exist.

Comment: Can i create new account?

Comment: SQL Server has 'sa' as an admin account by default. You've entered the password for it when you created the database. Try with that account.

Comment: your connection string is not complete. Try this, create a text file with extension .UDL then doubleclick on it. Now you get a form where you can visually edit a connectionstring and test it. When it works, open the file with notepad and there you will see the correct connectionstring to use

Comment: now issue is solved but

Comment: but the problem is i have installed sql server 2008 and 2012 in plesk and my databse file is in 2014 so when i try to install sql server 2014 then it wont getting installed because of previous versions and i cant delete the previous versions in plesk it is saying "Canot be removed"